# How to create HashMap, using value retrieved from Database?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns, enums, functional-interface

I have a database column which contains values from 0 to 10
Based on value retrieved from database, i need to create a HashMap

Example: If I get value from 0 to 6, I need to store 'sad' in HashMap
         If I get value from 7 to 8 , I need to store 'ok' in HashMap
         If I get value from 9 to 10, I need to store 'happy' in HashMap

I know one way to do it like

```
if (value.equals("1") || value.equals("2") || value.equals("3")..... || value.equals("6"){
map.put (value,"sad")
}
else if (value.equals("7") || value.equals("8")){
map.put(value, "ok")
} else{
map.put(value, "happy")
}
```

I am not sure if this is the Correct way to do it or not? Because if there are more values from lets say 0 to 50, it would be cumbersome. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Are they actually strings? (Which seems like the wrong data type for a number.)

Comment: Do you store the value as String in DB? If they are actually numeric, it is better to do the mapping using comparison operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Java `enum`. Define an `enum` that contains all your message mappings linked to the associated numbers. Then create an API in this enum to reverse look for the enum constant that contains a specific number and use that API to resolve what to put in your map.

The following is a working demo of this approach, you can run it to see how it works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class EnumSelector {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> store = new HashMap<>();
        
        store.computeIfAbsent(1, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(4, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(8, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(10, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(35, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(0, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(40, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(25, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(33, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(55, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(-1, EmotionalState::findLabel);
        store.computeIfAbsent(100, EmotionalState::findLabel);

        System.out.println(store);
    }

    public static enum EmotionalState {
        NULL("Null"), // No levels
        SINGLE("Single", 0), // Single level of 0
        COMBO_ENUM("Combo", 20, 30, 40, 50, 60), // From 20-30 + 40, 50, 60
        ENUMERATED("Enumerated", 33, 33, 28, 55), // From 33-33 + 28, 55
        
        SAD("Sad", 1, 6), 
        OK("Ok", 7, 8), 
        HAPPY("Happy", 9, 15),
        DEFAULT_STATE("Default");
        
        private String name;
        private List<Integer> levels;
        
        EmotionalState(String name, int... levels) {
            this.name = name;

            // The first two values will be considered as range
            IntStream initialStream = (levels.length < 2) ? 
                    Arrays.stream(levels) : // Single value
                    IntStream.range(levels[0], levels[1] + 1); // Range of values
            
            this.levels = initialStream
                    .mapToObj(Integer::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            // Add remaining values as literals
            if (levels.length > 2)
                Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(levels, 2, levels.length))
                    .mapToObj(Integer::new)
                    .forEach(this.levels::add);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean containsLevel(int level) {
            return levels.stream()
                    .filter(l -> l.intValue() == level)
                    .findAny()
                    .isPresent();
        }
        
        public static EmotionalState findFor(int level) {
            return Stream.of(EmotionalState.values())
                    .filter(en -> en.containsLevel(level))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(DEFAULT_STATE);
        }
        
        public static String findLabel(String level) {
            return findLabel(Integer.parseInt(level));
        }

        public static String findLabel(int level) {
            return EmotionalState.findFor(level).getName();
        }
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a59097202)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good Answer. A simpler variation, if the range of numbers for each enum is continuous, would be storing just the minimum and maximum. So, 1 & 6, 7 & 8, 9 & 10.

Comment: Thanks @Basil. Yes, I was thinking the same; but I opted for not adding that arbitrary constraint to the OP. That's why I even overloaded the save method to allow for `String` representations of numbers (as in the question) and hinted at the fact that this approach may arbitrarily allow negative numbers and an arbitrary default state, in case that was not desired by the OP and needed to be handled differently.

Comment: @Basil Actually you are correct, that would not have been an arbitrary constraint since I just noticed that the OP explicitly mentioned range based discriminator for the actual mapping. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I suggest keeping your enumerated version of code as well as a min-max version. (a) the Question is not clear, and (b) both will be helpful to other people.

Answer (score 0):

Use other hash map to store expected value and involve values based on your database value and put into your hashmap.
Database value would be key to your expected hashmap hm in below example.
for example:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  
hm.put(1,"Sad"); 
hm.put(2,"Sad"); 
hm.put(3,"Sad");
hm.put(7,"Ok");
hm.put(10,"Happy");
String expval = hm.get(3);
map.put(Value, expval)
```